# Failed to create bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I tried to run the following test code:

```
                package guru.springframework.test.external.props;

            import guru.springframework.test.jms.FakeJmsBroker;
            import guru.test.config.external.props.ExternalPropsEnvironment;
            import org.junit.Test;
            import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
            import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
            import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

            import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

            /**
             * Created by jt on 5/7/16.
             */
            @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
            @ContextConfiguration(classes = ExternalPropsEnvironment.class)
            public class PropertySourceEnvTest {

                @Autowired
                FakeJmsBroker fakeJmsBroker;

                @Test
                public void testPropsSet() throws Exception {
                assertEquals("10.10.10.123", fakeJmsBroker.getUrl());
                assertEquals(3330, fakeJmsBroker.getPort().intValue());
                assertEquals("Ron", fakeJmsBroker.getUser());
                assertEquals("Burgundy", fakeJmsBroker.getPassword());
                }

            }
```

Not sure why I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: guru.springframework.test.jms.FakeJmsBroker guru.springframework.test.external.props.PropertySourceEnvTest.fakeJmsBroker; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [guru.springframework.test.jms.FakeJmsBroker] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

FakeJmsBroker.java:

```
    package guru.springframework.test.jms;

/**
 * Created by jt on 5/7/16.
 */
public class FakeJmsBroker {

    private String url;
    private Integer port;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Integer getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(Integer port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is your entire source, it can't autowire it because it's not marked as one of the spring stereotypes that can be injected.  Add `@Component` to FakeJmsBroker

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, `FakeJmsBroker` is just a POJO.  Unless you either annotate it as `@Component`, `@Service`, etc, then Spring knows nothing about it.

You can also return a new instance of this as a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class.  However, looking at this class, unless it's holding properties, it doesn't make sense as a component as it doesn't contain any behavior.  Here's an example of making it a bean from a configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    // This will create an instance of FakeJmsBroker that will be in the Spring context
    @Bean
    public FakeJmsBroker createFakeBroker() {
       return new FakeJmsBroker();
    }
}
```

Either that class/method, or using the annotation-driven approach will make this bean eligible for autowiring.